# Bootstrap drop down menu remove default value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I have a drop down menu in html. When user select limit to 10 rows, when button clicked, 10 rows of data will be selected. But the drop down menu still display `"Limit to 5 rows"`. How to change the default value ?

```
 <div class="starter-template">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:20px">
                <form id="form" name="form" class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select id="limit" name="limit" class="form-control">
                            <option value="5">Limit to 5 rows</option>
                            <option value="10">Limit to 10 rows</option>
                            <option value="50">Limit to 50 rows</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/scoreLog", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String scoreLogList(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "limit", defaultValue = "5") Integer limit) {
        model.addAttribute("scoredList", txnLogRepository.findByScore(23, new PageRequest(0, limit)));
        return "scoreList";
    }
```

Comment: What templating library do you use? Thymeleaf? You would need to pass an argument to your model and render the template accordingly.

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski yes, thymeleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your controller add attribute to your model:

```
model.addAttribute("limit", limit);
```

It will expose the current value of limit to your template.

Then in your template you would need to modify the option tags:

```
<option value="5" th:selected="${limit == 5}">Limit to 5 rows</option>
<option value="10" th:selected="${limit == 10}">Limit to 10 rows</option>
<option value="50" th:selected="${limit == 50}">Limit to 50 rows</option>
```

See:

- http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes
- http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: thanks you , I thought I have to write a javascript to achieve this :P

Comment: If I have a datetime picker and I would like to display the time based on user input instead of showing default value, can I use this method as well ?

Comment: It might be slightly more complicated depending on the date time component, but the general answer for thymeleaf would be yes - you need to pass the arguments to template via model and render accordingly.